# Get Group information as non-admin from Google API

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

We have an application that sends mail merge emails via Google API. The specific scenario we want to handle is when a user is sending a mail merge to an organization group. I've been looking into the [Admin SDK Groups API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups) and it looks like it's something we would like to use. The information that we would like to grab is the number of members in the organization group, which would be `directMembersCount` in the returned object. However, the requirements of using this API are not quite suitable for our scenario because

1. It requires a super admin to manually enable Admin SDK for the organization.
2. The sender has to be an admin to make the API call to grab the Group data. Alternatively, the admin can delegate permission to a service account, but these are not feasible because we would have to request them for every organization that uses our app to send mail merges.

There's also a [Google blog post here](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/11/learn-more-about-google-groups-with.html) relevant to what we want. I tried adding a Google Group email recipient on the To field: I'm not an admin of the organization, but when I hover on the email, it shows details on the hovercard that would be useful to me, like number of members and number of subgroups. Is it possible to collect this type of information as a non-admin user with Google APIs?

Answer (score 1):

> but these are not feasible because we would have to request them for every organization that uses our app to send mail merges.

Create a [Marketplace app](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/overview), it is easy and the Service Account is ready to be used. This will allow you to add more features easily when you need to use other APIs, like contacts, or Gmail settings.

Comment: The reason I say it's not feasible is because, at this stage in our development, we really just care about the number of members in a Google Group, and whether or not they're nested groups (so that we can traverse and count the total number of members). It doesn't quite make sense for us to setup a Marketplace app just to grab the total number of recipients. Are there API's that allow us to access that data publicly (without this process and Service Accounts)?